# How get a route by controller name in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I created a menu system. Menu items are retrieved from the database. Each item has a controller column and an action column stating the destination to which it refers.  I need to get a route where the default controller is the same as provided by the controller menu. My goal is to generate a link to the menu using the url function:

```
$this->url('myRouteObtainedByControllerOfMenu', array('action' => "$queryMenu['action']"));
```

Comment: This might be tricky, as there isn't a one-to-one relationship between routes and controllers. You might be better off storing route names and params in the db instead of controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to determine the route from the controller name are building and querying an array of route/controller associations or perhaps configuring your router to use the controller name as a parameter.  However, you would probably be better off by having a `route` column in your menu database instead of a `controller` column because it saves steps:

> menu selection  -> associated controller name -> controller/router
>   discriminator -> associated router  -> associated controller -> some
>   action

is longer than

> menu selection  -> associated router  -> associated controller -> some
>   action